# .show() working but not .fadeIn(200)

Tags: javascript, lightbox

Why is it that I can .show() my 'overlay' div but not .fadeIn(200)?
And after the 'overlay' div is shown via .show() it does not fadeOut() as it would do if the div was never hidden in the first place and then clicked on.

```
CSS:
-----------

#overlay
{
    height:97%;
    width:99%;
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.8;
}

#batman
{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:-1;
}

#lightbox-img
{
    height:100px;
    width:200px;
    margin-left:600px;
    margin-top:270px;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
}



JavaScript:
-----------
window.onload = function()
{
  $("#overlay").hide();
}


$(document).ready(function(){
 //page is ready

    $("#overlay").on("click",function(){
      $('#overlay').fadeOut(1000);
    });

    $('#batman').on("click",function(){
      lightboxImg()
    });

  });


function lightboxImg()
{
  $('#overlay').hide().fadeIn(2000);

  var source = $('#batman').attr('src');
  var text = "<img src= \"" +  source +  "\"  id=\"lightbox-img\"></img> ";
  document.body.innerHTML = text + document.body.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: try using `.fadeOut(0)` and `.fadeIn(0)` in place of `.hide` and `.show` so that it applies the correct classes :)

Comment: also FYI `<img />` is a self closing tag.. you should use `/>` instead of `></img>`

Comment: It seems to work [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhwyzhm2/). Can you tell us what is not working for you?

Comment: If i do not hide the div onload then I am able to click on it and it will fadeOut however if I .hide it and then .show it by clicking on the batman image then it will no longer .fadeOut.    Additionally I can .show but not .fadeIn() when the batman img is clicked